# initMap is not a function

Tags: google-maps

I can't understand what is the problem? I used this example from Google Map APIs: [Simple Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

```
<body>
   <!-- Map Section -->
   <section id="map"></section>

   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5Y8CqFe-4Egzl5TlPqlFvjRGcuCfHGvY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
   
</body>
```

main.js:

```
//--------------------------------------------------
// Contact Map
//--------------------------------------------------
function initMap() {    
    if ($("#map").length > 0)
    {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            center: {lat: 44.4297538, lng: 26.0649221},
            zoom: 16,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            clickable: false
        });
        
    }
}
```

Error:

> message: "initMap is not a function"
>
> name: "InvalidValueError"

Answer (score 5):

Having the same issue, I personally removed the `&callback=initMap` to make it work.
Other threads seams to show that initMap is a function you should build yourself.

Comment: I had the same issue...your solution worked...removed the initMap from the script call and it worked.  Ironically, what through me for a quite some time is that I didn't even see that in the script line because I have a separate `initMap()` in another custom.js file - so I kept looking at it trying to figure what the issue was.  &callback=initMap is calling a function that hasn't loaded yet.  my custom.js file loads after the map script - on purpose...so initMap wasn't defined yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue working on a wordpress template with Sage (a WordPress starter theme).

My js was wrapped with

```
(function($) {

// all the functions to create map, center markers, etc.

}
```

Then, the map was initialize in `$(document).ready`

I removed `(function($) { }` and just add the functions without `$(document).ready` then it was ok.

Also, be sure to load the custom js file before the api google map :

```
<script src="custom-js-google-map.js"></script>

<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions offered were helping me. I finally came across dynamic loading of the script here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API

Because you are loading it in a separate js file the google map api's are not loading in the correct order with the function.

Doing this solved it for me:

```
// Create the script tag, set the appropriate attributes
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap';
script.defer = true;
    
// Attach your callback function to the `window` object
window.initMap = function() {
      // JS API is loaded and available
      // Throw your code within this, it will wait for the google api scripts to completely load
};
    
// Append the 'script' element to 'head'
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Hope this helps, I spent a day looking for solution.

Comment: My script was working fine, but since I added other scripts this start happening to me. After appliying this it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try move in head the loading for script

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5Y8CqFe-4Egzl5TlPqlFvjRGcuCfHGvY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

and be sure for right path  for

```
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

eventually try using relative path

```
     <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! but i still have the same error.

Comment: of course, i checked it. index.html and contact.html are in the root directory. so, i don't need to use ./

Comment: Try putting the function within the same file (to be sure it works). And make sure __initMap()__ loads without waiting like when using __$(document).ready__