# Google map getting "initMap is not a function" in chrome browser only

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Google map getting "initMap is not a function" in chrome browser only.

In other browsers (Firefox, IE, etc ) are working fine.

I am using the Google MAP API for location search and autocomplete location.

The similar question answers I had tried. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319676/initmap-is-not-a-function-in-using-google-maps-api),(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448238/initmap-is-not-a-function)
Not working yet in Chrome.

Here is the code.

```
<script>function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: 34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 2
});
}    
</script>

<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{KEY}}&callback=initMap">
    </script>
<div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The posted code works fine for me in Chrome ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ybt1rsux/3/)). Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The script should be on the below section. It can't find the "map" div hence creates a problem that leads to "initMap is not a function" problem.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    // scripts goes here
</script>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{KEY}}&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```